# row-wise differences between two large matrices in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix

I would like to ask an opinion on how to speed up the following operation.

I have two matrices says A and B with n rows and 3 columns; for any row vector of A I want to compare its difference with any row vector of B. So it is a pairwise difference between *all* row vectors of the two matrices. The resulting matrix is then a n*n matrix. Then I want to apply a function to any element of this, the biharm() function that I wrote in the example. The problem is that, while for small matrices I have no problems, I have the necessity to apply this operation to very large matrices such as 1000*3. In the sigm() function, that I wrote to do that, I first initialize S and then I wrote two annidated for cycles. However, this is slow for large matrices. Does anyone has an idea on how to speed up this? I think using apply() but I cannot figure out the correct way. Here below a fully reproducible example. Thanks in advance for any advice. Best, Paolo.

```
biharm<-function(vec1,vec2){
  reso<-norm(as.matrix(vec1)-as.matrix(vec2),type="F")^2*log(norm((as.matrix(vec1)-as.matrix(vec2)),type="F"))
  reso
}
sigm<-function(mat1,mat2=NULL){
  tt<-mat1
  if(is.null(mat2)){yy<-mat1}else{yy<-mat2}
  k<-nrow(yy)
  m<-ncol(yy)
  SGMr<-matrix(rep(0,k^2),ncol=k)
  for(i in 1:k){
    for(j in 1: k){
      SGMr[i,j]<-biharm(yy[i,],tt[j,])
    }}
  SGMr<-replace(SGMr,which(SGMr=="NaN",arr.ind=T),0)
  return(SGMr)}


### small matrices example:
A<-matrix(rnorm(30),ncol=3)
B<-matrix(rnorm(30),ncol=3)
sigm(A,B)

### large matrices example:
A<-matrix(rnorm(900),ncol=3)
B<-matrix(rnorm(900),ncol=3)
sigm(A,B)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is about 8 times faster on my system.

```
biharm.new <- function(vec1,vec2){
  n <- sqrt(sum((vec1-vec2)^2))
  n^2*log(n)
}

sigm.new<-function(mat1,mat2=NULL){
  tt<-mat1
  if(is.null(mat2)){yy<-mat1}else{yy<-mat2}
  SGMr <- apply(tt,1,function(t)apply(yy,1,biharm.new,t))
  replace(SGMr,which(SGMr=="NaN",arr.ind=T),0)
}
### large matrices example:
set.seed(1)
A<-matrix(rnorm(900),ncol=3)
B<-matrix(rnorm(900),ncol=3)
system.time(result.1<-sigm(A,B))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    6.13    0.00    6.13 
system.time(result.2<-sigm.new(A,B))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.81    0.00    0.81 
all.equal(result.1,result.2)
# [1] TRUE
```

The use of `apply(...)` results in about a 3-fold improvement. The rest comes from optimizing `biharm(...)` - since you are calling this 810,000 times it pays to make it as efficient as possible.

Note that the Frobenius norm is just the Euclidean norm, so if that is what you really want use `sqrt(sum(x^2))` rather than converting to matrices and using `norm(...)`. The former is *much* faster.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
set.seed(1)
foo<-matrix(runif(30),nc=3)
bar<-matrix(runif(30),nc=3)

sapply(1:10,function(j) sapply(1:10,function(k) biharm(bar[k,],foo[j,])) )
```

EDIT -- basically same as jhoward's "sigm.new" without the error checking.  Clearly `biharm.new` is a winner.

```
microbenchmark(carl(foo,bar),jhoward(foo,bar),times=3)
Unit: milliseconds
              expr       min       lq    median       uq      max neval
    carl(foo, bar) 5846.8273 6071.364 6295.8999 6322.425 6348.951     3
 jhoward(foo, bar)  891.5734  934.550  977.5267 1008.388 1039.248     3
```